# onStop() online status issue - home screen vs previous activity

Tags: java, android

im using the onStop method to determine when the app closes from the home activity (specifically using either the home button on device or task manager button on device) it doesnt set a timestamp to signify the user was last online at (timestamp) in the firebase database. however, when onStop is called for all other activities it remains as online = true, which is correct.

```
// Home button pressed + task button pressed + leaving activity
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        mUserDatabase.child("Online").setValue(currentDate);
    }
}
```

Is there any way i can specify if onStop is called from home activity, option a) will put timestamp in the database, or, option b) does not change online status on database (as user is still in app, but on another activity).

Comment: You can use a single-Activity approach, if you do that then your Activity will reliably tell you if the app is in background or not. You can also use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`.

Comment: processlifecycleowner actually seems like something i should look into, foreground vs background code seems quite handy. :) - thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class like this :-

```
public class MalikChat extends Application {

    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (!isUserLoggedOut(this)) {
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child(onlineStatusTable).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                            mUserDatabase.child("status").onDisconnect().setValue(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your session is expired, Please login again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                setUserLoggedOut(this, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or in your manifest file :-

```
<application
        **android:name=".offlineHalper.MalikChat"**
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chat_group"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_chat_group"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

if you want to set user status then set this method in your all activities like this :-

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        userStatus("online");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        userStatus(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        super.onPause();
    }
```

userStatus Method :-

```
public static void userStatus(String status) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(onlineStatusTable).child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        try {
            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("status", status);
            reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: leave a comment in if you have any query

Comment: this may help for another issue i have, but my big problem right now is if i go from activity 2 -> activity 1(home) using the back button i stay online on database. if i go from activity 1(home) to home screen of my device using the back button, it shows me offline (also correct). however if i use the device home/task manager button and leave the app it doesnt update the status on database to show the user is no longer in the app, thus it shows them online when the app is in the background/closed entirely. i just noticed since changing the code this seems to be the same for every activity.

Comment: needs to be a way to specify if home button on device/task manager button on device is pressed, update database to show user is offline. because wherever you press those 2 buttons the outcome is the same thing: user is NOT in the app anymore. something i can use such as onDestroy / if app is in background / if app is destroyed = user offline. i fixed back button issue between activities to show online always unless from home activity to device home (offline). back button is fine. its the device home button/task manager button causing me a headache.

Comment: i have updated my answer according to your situation